# MySQL query to find location of the last entry of an device

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables (in a SQL Server database) as following:

```
create table tblDevices(
idDevice varchar(255) not null,
(...)
primary key(idGUID));

create table tblEnvironmentLog(
ID int not null auto_increment,
idDevice varchar(30) not null,
txtLocation    varchar(255),
datDate    date,
datTime    time,
primary key(ID));
```

Each event in `tblEnvironmentLog` belongs to a device in `tblDevice`, and each record has a date and a location(<- location of the device). An device may have several records(at least one).

I need a SQL query that finds for each `idDevice` in `tblDevices` the `location` of the latest record among all its record.

I've tried to write the query for long time, but couldn't find the solution, so any help or hint will be welcomed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some sort of effort to try a query. Then we can help you resolve it. Show sample data from both tables as well. Also, what RDBMS are you actually using? Remove what you are not using.

Comment: Another thing... How can you have `idDevice varchar(255)` in the `tblDevices` table and `idDevice varchar(30)` in the `tblEnvironmentLog` table. Might be some truncation issues there.

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically want to get the rows that correspond to the latest date/time for each device.  You've specified both MySQL and SQL Server.  This is for SQL Server.

```
SELECT *
FROM tblDevices t1
    INNER JOIN tblEnvironmentLog t2 
        ON t1.idDevice = t2.idDevice
WHERE t2.ID = (SELECT TOP 1 t3.ID 
               FROM tblEnvironmentLog t3 
               WHERE t2.idDevice = t3.idDevice 
               ORDER BY t3.datDate DESC, t3.datTime DESC)
```

Comment: How can you order by `datDate` and `datTime` when you aren't joining the `tblEnvironmentLog`?

Comment: @WEI_DBA Oops... When I started editing, I didn't see both tables.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this -

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.datDate, t2.datTime
FROM tblDevices t1
JOIN tblEnvironmentLog t2 on t1.idDevice = t2.idDevice
WHERE t2.id in ( SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tblEnvironmentLog GROUP BY idDevice)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a query like below. In case you need to know better about how to add date time individual components correctly, [see this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51440/how-to-combine-date-and-time-to-datetime2-in-sql-server)

**Explanation:**
We use an inner query (as E) to find the max date time per `idDevice`, and then join it to `tblDevices` (as D) as well as `tblEnvironmentLog` (as E2) to get desired results.

**Query**

```
select 
DISTINCT -- this is needed as many result pair may come up with same values
D.iDDevice, E2.Location
from tblDevices D left join
(
Select 
idDevice, 
max( cast(datDate as datetime)+cast (datTime as dattime)) as dt 
from tblEnvironmentLog  
group by idDevice) E 
on D.idDevice =E.idDevice 
left join tblEnvironmentLog E2 on E.idDevice=E2.idDevice and 
cast(E2.datDate as datetime)+cast(E2.datTime as datetime)=E.dt
```